# Nested FormArray in MatTable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have several dynamic tables, which should be combined with a form since each row includes a checkbox.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
@for (service of dataSource; track dataSource; let tableIndex = $index) {
     <table mat-table *ngIf="dataSource && dataSource[tableIndex]" [dataSource]="dataSource[tableIndex]" formArrayName="services">
       <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
           {{element.serviceIsSelected}} <-- This returns either true or false
           <mat-checkbox formControlName="serviceIsSelected"></mat-checkbox>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to combine the dataSource with the form.

This is my dataSource:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": true
    },
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": false
    },
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": true
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": false
    }
  ]
]
```

As you see, it is a 2-dimensional array. Before, the formControl `serviceIsSelected` was a single array only. I tried to simplify this case and now the ouput of `this.form.get('services')?.getRawValue()` is

```json
[
  [
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": true
    },
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": false
    },
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": true
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "serviceIsSelected": false
    }
  ]
]
```

, which is exactly the same as `dataSource`. However, `dataSource` seems to work properly but in terms of the formControl, the browser indicates the error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'services -> serviceIsSelected'

This is the structure of my entire form:

```
FormGroup
 - controls
 - services: FormArray
  - controls: Array(2)
   - 0: FormArray
    - controls: Array(3)
     - 0: FormControl
      - value
       - serviceIsSelected: true
       ...
```